# In Paypal's Payments Standard 'Shipping Calculations' settings, how does the 'Currency' dropdown work

Tags: paypal

I’m specifically asking about the **Currency** dropdown menu setting in the **Shipping Calculations** (Paypal's Payments Standard):

[Screengrab here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHpNp.png)

If, for example, I’m selling an item on my website priced at 10 Euro, but I have set separate shipping prices for ‘Euro' and 'British Pounds', will a buyer paying in British Pounds be charged the different shipping rates I’ve set?

Or, will the British Pounds settings only be used if I’m **selling** in British Pounds?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is totally unrelated to programming.

Comment: A genuine question related to website development using Paypal. The Paypal developer support page refers to here: https://developer.paypal.com/support/

Answer (score 0):

So Paypal eventually responded:

I am sorry if there has been any confusion regarding your query. I have double-checked you query and have tested this myself.
The postage calculations can only be set to one currency, for example Euros or Pounds. This section will not allow for different calculations depending on which country or currency the funds have been received from.